# How to generate multiple particles at once?

Tags: unity, particles

I am tying to create a cartoony balloon-pop animation. I want there to be particles that come from all sides of a sphere. However they should all come at once, in a single burst.

What I've done is this. I generated a particle system as a child of the sphere. I set the shape to sphere, reduced the duration, and increased the rate. However it doesn't seem like any particles are being generated at the same time still, only one is created at once.

[image]

How can I make all of the particles come at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a "Burst" and it's part of the particle system's emission properties: [Burst (scripting reference)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.Burst.html).

> A burst is a particle emission event, where a number of particles are all emitted at the same time.

You can get some help from the Unity documentation with this [explosion example](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PartSysExplosion.html), and this page on the [EmissionModule](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PartSysEmissionModule.html).